# dgrid is calling rest store twice when first loaded

Tags: dgrid, dstore

Here is my problem. I define a Rest DSTORE, and a DGRID using it. My problem is that when dgrid is first loaded, it is calling rest service twice. Can anybody help me to understand why ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities but without any code no one can help you. Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks Ferry, I figured out that I was calling startup() method twice. In some cases, it fires two calls to rest service.